# Issues with importing a module twice

Tags: reactjs, vite, dayjs

I have an issue, which I assume is down to compilation doing some deduplication of modules.

I have two utils files using `dayjs`:

###### dates-normal.js

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs'
import 'dayjs/locale/en-gb.js'
dayjs.locale('en-gb')
import relativeTime from 'dayjs/plugin/relativeTime.js'

dayjs.extend(relativeTime)

export const dateAgo = (date) => {
    return dayjs(date).from(dayjs())
}
```

###### dates-no-rounding.js

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs'
import 'dayjs/locale/en-gb.js'
dayjs.locale('en-gb')
import relativeTime from 'dayjs/plugin/relativeTime.js'

dayjs.extend(relativeTime, { rounding: (a) => a }) // override rounding

export const dateAgo = (date) => {
    return dayjs(date).from(dayjs())
}
```

I would expect the following...

```
import { dateAgo } from './dates-normal.js'
console.log(dateAgo('2023-06-01')) // 6 months ago
```

But instead it picks up the overriding of the rounding feature, and gives me `6.381520601478495 months ago`

I'm guessing this is some sort of treeshaking / de-duplication at compile time, but I can't figure out how to override it. Changing the import and export names makes no difference.

Any suggestions?